# How can I delete a specific repetitive number in a list?

Tags: python, list

For example I have

```
[3, 4, 5, 5, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 17, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want delete just all the zeros. 
Note: assume that we have an unknown number of zeros in a list that has an unknown length.

Comment: `[elm for elm in list_var if elm != 0]`

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions make this easy:

```
new_list = [x for x in orig_list if x != 0]
```

You can push the work to the C layer with `filter`:

```
# If they're all numbers, you can avoid work by using filter with None:
new_list = list(filter(None, orig_list))  # List wrapper not needed on Py2

# If falsy values that aren't numeric zero might be found, and should be kept, you'd do:
new_list = list(filter((0).__ne__, orig_list))  # List wrapper not needed on Py2
```

Comment: Nice use of `filter`!